# Xamarin.Forms Navigation (Memory Management)

Tags: memory-management, xamarin.forms, memory-leaks, navigation

Suppose I have 5 pages that I need to open one after another, and I don't want to go back actually. I can subscribe and unsubscribe the event on OnAppearing and OnDisAppearing to avoid memory leaks. But all the pages will be in the Navigation stack and it will consume memory. So how to remove those pages from memory, or how to efficiently navigate?

Comment: Agree with FreakyAli's answer and you can use [custom renderer of page](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/357728/#Comment_357728) to check if the page is disposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you never have to go back in the Navigation Stack if that is the case the smart way would be to never create one and just change the MainPage property to the new page that you want to use something like below:

```
Application.Current.MainPage= new NewMainPage();
```